# Understanding the behaviour of Logical Indices

Tags: r, indexing, logical-operators

I have the following snippet

```
x <- 20:1
x
x[c(T, F, NA)] <- 1
x
[1]  1 19 18  1 16 15  1 13 12  1 10  9  1  7  6  1  4  3  1  1
```

I do not understand how the result has been generated. I thought T = 1, F = 0 and NA is treated as false (so NA = 0) as well.

So I expected the following result:

```
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Could anyone explain to me what `R` is doing? Is thers some kind of hidden "If ... then"-Statement? `20, 17, 14, 11, 8...` are apparently `True` but why?

Comment: Study `help("[")`. Everything is explained there. And you shouldn't use R without having understood most of the content in this help page.

Comment: Note the non-`NA` elements in this expression: `x[rep_len(c(T, F, NA), length(x))]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first check ,

```
x[T]
#[1] 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
```

and then

```
x[F]
#integer(0)
```

Also check,

```
x[NA]
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

R uses cyclic indexing (not sure if this is the right word)

Now, when you do

```
x[c(T, F, NA)]
```

it gives,

```
#[1] 20 NA 17 NA 14 NA 11 NA  8 NA  5 NA  2
```

it prints all the `T` values, ignores all the `F` values and gives `NA` in place of all `NA` values.

Now when you assign

```
x[c(T, F, NA)] <- 1
```

Only the indexes which has index as `T` gets replaced with 1, rest all are as it is,  giving

```
#[1]  1 19 18  1 16 15  1 13 12  1 10  9  1  7  6  1  4  3  1  1
```

As commented by @alexis_laz, for `NA`s quoting from the document

> When extracting, a numerical, logical or character NA index picks an unknown element and so returns NA in the corresponding element of a logical, integer, numeric, complex or character result, and NULL for a list.
>
> When replacing (that is using indexing on the lhs of an assignment) NA does not select any element to be replaced. As there is ambiguity as to whether an element of the rhs should be used or not, this is only allowed if the rhs value is of length one

To summarize, while extracting `x[NA]` it returns as `NA` and while replacing `x[NA] <-`  it does not select any element to be replaced.

Comment: I guess it would be more suitable to inspect the behaviour of `"[<-"` and not `"["` when `NA`s are used as indices. As `?"["` states, `x[NA`] returns `NA` while `x[NA] = value` is ignored.

Comment: First off, thanks for your answers! ?"[" and ?"[<-" gives me the same help page (Extract or Replace Parts of an Object)